Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction is null when running automated tests
We are running a set of SpecFlow tests against our Sitecore 10.2 Content Delivery site.
As part of our code, we generate trace information for current tracking session.
When running the tests on our local machine or manually on our self hosted build agent VM, we don't encounter any issues. However, when the tests are run with the ChromeDriver on the build agent triggered through the Azure DevOps pipeline, we encounter a 500 error:

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error stems from this line of code:
var pages = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.Pages;

and we have found that

Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction

is null when we are running through the tests.
We tried setting the AutoDetectBots setting to 'false' as per this: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-platform/configure-robot-detection-functionality.html#disable-robot-detection, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Adding the 'enableTracking' property with a value of 'false' to the Site Settings 'Other properties' resolves the issue, but we do want to keep the tracking functionality, and also not add a null check for

Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction

because we would then be taking a different path through our code when performing operations on our site through the automation tests compared to when actual users use our site.

Have you checked on IgnoreRobots setting in Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config file? By default it is set to true which means that that robot visits are ignored and not saved to xDB.
